# Magento 2 search customization

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

i want to implement search as below image

[image]

1st text box will get the result based on product name and SKU

and 2nd text box will get the result based on CAS number(custom attribute)

any help will be appreciate